# How to pass a node as a parameter along with other types to a function with ajax in umbraco

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, umbraco

I'm trying to pass a node and two strings as parameters to a JsonResult in umbraco. When I debug the method, the node var has no value. Here is the javascript

```
        function newsSub() {
        if(validateForm('newsSubscriptionForm') == true)
        {
            var name = document.forms["newsSubForm"]["name"].value;//The input name
            var email = document.forms["newsSubForm"]["email"].value;//The input email
            var node = '@SiteNode';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Umbraco/Surface/AjaxSurface/Newsletter',
                data: {"name":name, "email":email, "node":node},
                dataType: 'json',
                cache:false,
                success:function(data){
                    var success = data.Success;
                    var test = data.test;
                    if(success == true){
                        document.getElementById("sendTrue").style.display='inline';
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("sendFalse").style.display='inline';
                    }
                    //success:function (result) {//Om de waarde van een string op te halen die naar een jsonresult geretourneerd wordt.
                    //    alert(result);
                }
            })
            document.getElementById("newsSubscriptionForm").style.display='none';
        }
    };
```

And here is the c#

```
    public JsonResult Newsletter(String name, String email, Node node)
    {
        INode iNode = node;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            NewsSubscriptiontFormModel model = new NewsSubscriptiontFormModel();
            model.Email = email;
            model.Name = name;

            Dictionary<String, String> userData = new Dictionary<String, String>();

            foreach (var prop in typeof(NewsSubscriptiontFormModel).GetProperties())
            {
                if (prop.GetValue(model, null) != null)
                {
                    userData.Add(prop.Name, (prop.GetValue(model, null) ?? "").ToString());
                }
            }

            //return Json(userData["Name"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);//Om te kijken of alles dat opgestuurd wordt wel waarde heeft.
            if (Mailing.GenerateAndSendMail(userData, iNode))
            {
                return Json(new { Success = true });
            }
        }
        return Json(new { Success = false });
    }
```

I probably need to convert whatever has to be typed after data:
but how?

Answer (score 0):

Thats not possible. 
I suggest you to send the node id only, and then find the node in your c#.

So find the id in your javascript:

```
var nodeId = @CurrentPage.Id;
...
data: {"name":name, "email":email, "nodeId":nodeId},
```

C#:

```
public JsonResult Newsletter(String name, String email, int nodeId)
    {
        var node = new Node(nodeId);
....
```

Comment: Fixed it!! Like this though:                                                                              var node = new Node(nodeId);
                INode iNode = node;                                                                            Thank you dear sir!! I hope you'll prosper!

Comment: @devKoen cool it worked! Please accept the answer so other people can see its closed.